# no method error when trying to initialize rack session cookies

Tags: ruby, cookies, rubygems, rack

I'm using no frameworks, only the rack gem to build a web application. I'm trying to set cookies to an successfully logged user:

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb:155:in `<class:Cookie>': undefined method `DelegateClass' for Rack::Session::Cookie:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I already tried to specify rack version as

```
gem "rack", "~> 3.0"
```

but nothing changed.

How to fix it?

Comment: Is there a stacktrace we could see? :)

Comment: Actually never mind - what ruby version do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably recently updated from rack version 2 to 3. Or you are following a tutorial or documentation for rack version 2 but while running rack 3.

Quote from rack's [UPGRADE-GUIDE.md](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/696ed9e8f48053683a0a19fc68eb49f094c0efcb/UPGRADE-GUIDE.md?plain=1#L86C1-L98C4):

> #### `Rack::Session` was moved to a separate gem.
>
> Previously, `Rack::Session` was part of the `rack` gem. Not every application
> needs it, and it increases the security surface area of the `rack`, so it was
> decided to extract it into its own gem `rack-session` which can be updated
> independently.
>
> Applications that make use of `rack-session` will need to add that gem as a
> dependency:
>
> ```rb
> gem 'rack-session'
> ```

Comment: I only specified the rack to ~> 3.0 after the error appeared (was rack 2.2.7) but nothing changed, I also tried to require the rack-session gem after installing it as `require 'rack/session '` but it didn't worked too it shows the "cannot load such file -- rack/session (LoadError)" error

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` after adding `gem 'rack-session'` to your `Gemfile`?

Comment: yes I did, the path to the gem shown with the error is `C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/...` looks like the application is using the 2.2.7 version of rack

Comment: Do you use `bundle exec ...` to start your application?

Comment: I'm just running the server with `system("^C^C")
system("rackup config.ru")` with a gem that triggers the command every time I save the file, didn't use bundle exec